# Cloudwatch logs "AND NOT" search

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm searching Cloudwatch log events for errors with the following criteria:

```
?"error" ?"ERROR" ?"Error:"
```

How can I exclude specific terms from the result? For example, if I don't care about `specific_error`, how can I specify not to match on it?

I'm expecting to be able to do something like:

```
(?"error" AND -"specific_error") ?"ERROR" ?"Error:"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CloudWatch console, this can be accomplished with the `-` operand before the term you wish to exclude:

```
"error" -"something minor happened"
```

This is from the [AWS docs for "Matching terms in log events"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#matching-terms-events).

[image: cloudwatch exclusive filter]

Similarly, using `aws logs tail`, you can pass this to the `--filter-pattern` argument:

```
$ aws logs tail --format short /aws/lambda/my_lambda --filter-pattern '"error" -"something minor happened"' --since 3h

2021-07-09T19:28:47 error:   something bad happened
2021-07-09T19:28:51 error:   something bad happened
2021-07-09T19:29:52 error:   something REALLY bad happened
2021-07-09T19:30:15 error:   something CATASTROPHIC happened! Aiee!
2021-07-09T19:30:36 error:   something bad happened
```